# How to wait till desired event is fired and only then return promise

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener

I am opening a new window on my website where i have to wait till the user does a transaction on another website.
I will then receive a postMessage call once the transaction is complete.
How do i wait and only return once the even is fired?

This is a short example of the code:

```
async function anonTransaction() -> Promise {

const popupWindow = window.open("http://localhost:3000/")

let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
window.onmessage = (event) => {
        if(event.origin !== "http://localhost:3000"){
            reject()
        }
        else{
            console.log("resolve");
            resolve()
        }    
}});
}
```

/// on the opened website

```
let targetWebsite = window.opener;
targetWebsite.postMessage("message");
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is wrong with your code? Do you get an error? Do your logging statements ever get called?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering, why don't you just execute your logic within onmessage?

```js
window.onmessage = (event) => {
    if(event.origin === "http://localhost:3000"){
        // execute your logic here
        myAsyncFunction();
    }  
};
```

If you really want a promise, you can try and create a global onmessage event listener which rejects or resolves a promise by saving the referrences to resolve and reject:

```js
let resolve;
let reject;

let result = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    resolve = res;
    reject = rej;
});

window.onmessage = (event) => {
    if(event.origin !== "http://localhost:3000"){
        if(reject) reject()
    } else{
        console.log("resolve");
        if(resolve) resolve()
    }    
};
```